# SQLLDR for Azure SQL Server?

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-loader, azure-sql-server

I have bash script running in **Ubuntu**  that uses the SQLLDR to load **additional data** into Oracle database from CSV file.

We are migrating to Azure SQL server and I am asked to convert the script so that it will load the **additional data** into Azure SQL server.

How do I do it? I don't want to use ADF, is there any simple solution available ? Can I use Azure SQL BCP to **additional data** into Azure SQL server and Can it be installed on **Ubuntu** ?

Comment: This is a rather broad question IMO. You may want to check out data integration service like [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/)

Comment: we load a limited amount of data(in CSV) into Oracle using SQLLDR, is there an easy way to convert this bash script to support Azure SQL server ?

Comment: If you are just looking for loading CSVs into existing tables in Azure SQL, [BCP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/bcp-and-sql-azure/) could be useful for you.

Comment: Can I use the BCP to load additional data on the existing database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it done using BCP tool

```
bcp Database.Schema.Persons format nul -c -t, -f Categoriesformat.fmt -S tcp:demo.database.windows.net -U User1 -P P@$$word!

bcp Database.Schema.Persons in "W:\test_load_data.csv" -t , -f Categoriesformat.fmt -S tcp:demo.database.windows.net -U User1 -P P@$$word!
```

**Reference:**
[SQL Server BCP insert additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372925/sql-server-bcp-insert-additional-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, As per official documentation, Azure Data factory does not support bash script to sink data in Oracle from other sources.

As given in comment by you, If you have limited amount of data. You can use Copy Activity in Azure data factory.

Refer - [Copy data from and to Oracle by using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory)

Comment: ADF would be over kill for the amount of data that I am trying to insert.